# Using method of image to find surface charge density

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatic

**Two point charges of 50nC and -20nC are located at (-3,2,4) and (1,0,5) above the conducting ground plane z=2. Calculate: a)The surface charge density at (7,-2,2), b)\$\vec D\$ at (1,1,1)**
Now, according to method of image there are \$50\$nC charge at \$(-3,2,4)\$ and \$-50\$nC charge at \$(-3,2,0)\$.
For, 50nC charge,
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec R_1&{\begin{aligned}\\
=7\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+2\hat a_z&-(-3\hat a_x+2\hat a_y+4\hat a_z)\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&=10\hat a_x-4\hat a_y-2\hat a_z\\
\end{align}\\\$
For -50nC charge,
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec R_2&{\begin{aligned}\\
=7\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+2\hat a_z&-(-3\hat a_x+2\hat a_y)\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&=10\hat a_x-4\hat a_y+2\hat a_z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\therefore\vec D&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\frac{50\times 10^{-9}(10\hat a_x-4\hat a_y-2\hat a_z)}{[10^2+(-4)^2+(-2)^2]^{3/2}}-\frac{50\times 10^{-9}(10\hat a_x-4\hat a_y+2\hat a_z)}{[10^2+(-4)^2+2^2]^{3/2}}\right]\\
&=-12.11\hat a_z\times 10^{-12}\\
\end{align}\\\$
Again, according to method of image there are \$-20\$nC charge at \$(1,0,5)\$ and \$20\$nC charge at \$(1,0,-1)\$.
For -20nC charge,
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec R_1&=7\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+2\hat a_z-(\hat a_x+5\hat a_z)\\
&=6\hat a_x-2\hat a_y-3\hat a_z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec R_2&=7\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+2\hat a_z-(\hat a_x-\hat a_z)\\
&=6\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+3\hat a_z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\therefore\vec D&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[-\frac{20\times 10^{-9}(6\hat a_x-2\hat a_y-3\hat a_z)}{[6^2+(-2)^2+(-3)^2]^{3/2}}+\frac{20\times 10^{-9}(6\hat a_x-2\hat a_y+3\hat a_z)}{[6^2+(-2)^2+3^2]^{3/2}}\right]\\
&=27.84\hat a_z\times 10^{-12}\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\therefore\$ Total
\$\vec D=15.73\hat a_z\times 10^{-12}\$
We know, surface charge density
\$\sigma=\vec D.\hat a_n\$
Now, as the point is on the plane I can't understand what will be the normal vector \$(\hat a_n)\$, upward or downward. Please anyone help. (The answer is \$6.41\times 10^{-12}\$)

Comment: Is this question a repeat of your [previous one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536600/using-method-of-image-to-find-potential-difference-and-electric-field)?

Comment: @Andyaka no no, it looks same, but my doubt is different.